# How to make Visual Studio use Ambari local user instead of default 'admin' while submitting hive query to HDInsight cluster

Tags: visual-studio, azure-hdinsight, ambari

This question is in the context of HDInsight Hadoop (Linux) cluster. Once we login to Azure account through Visual Studio , based on whichever Azure subscriptions are added to our account we can see the list of HDInsight clusters in those subscriptions in the Server Explorer -- and then we can simply write/submit hive queries to those clusters directly. This doesn't involve any authentication -- as it happens behind the scenes seamlessly. But when we do that , the submitted hive queries use the default 'admin' as the user. What if I have created some local Ambari user and I would like Visual Studio to use that instead of the default 'admin'? Is there any way to force Visual Studio to use local Ambari user?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a local Ambari user. You can Link to or edit a cluster in Visual Studio.

> To link an HDInsight cluster:

1. **Right-click HDInsight**, and then select **Link a HDInsight Cluster** to
   display the **Link a HDInsight Cluster** dialog box.
2. Enter a **Connection Url** in the form
   `https://CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net`. The **Cluster Name**
   automatically fills in with the cluster name portion of your URL
   when you go to another field. Then enter a **Username** and **Password**,
   and select **Next**.

[image]

3. Select **Finish**. If the cluster linking is successful, the cluster is then listed under the **HDInsight** node.

To update a linked cluster, **right-click** the cluster and select **Edit**. You can then update the cluster information.

**Reference:**  [Azure HDInsight - Link to or edit a cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-visual-studio-tools-get-started#link-to-or-edit-a-cluster)

Comment: I tried this -- But it appears this local user name (e.g. I used testuser) is only used in authenticating at the time of HDI cluster link creation -- thereafter whenever we submit any job to that linked cluster , it continues to use 'admin' only. So from job execution point of view nothing really changes